# 2D Java arrays not displaying properly

Tags: java, arrays

I am creating arrays in Java and doing a little quiz game in the terminal. The arrays are not showing all the options when I sout the program.

When I am printing the arrays I can only start at [1] [1] | [2] [2] | [3] [3] | [4] [4] | and that forces me to only have a few slots for questions.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{

    //This is a short program that uses 2d arrays to do a quiz about tolkien characters

    public static void main(String[] args){
    String quiz[] = new String[4];
       


        String quiz2D[][] = new String[9][9];

        //creating questions and assigning them positions
        quiz2D[0][0] = "What is gandalf?";
        quiz2D[0][1] = "Valar";
        quiz2D[0][2] = "Maiar";
        quiz2D[0][3] = "Ainur";
        quiz2D[0][4] = "Dwarf";
        quiz2D[0][5] = "Hobbit";

        quiz2D[1][1] = "Who was the original and first evil tolkien character chronologically?!";
        quiz2D[1][2] = "Sauron";
        quiz2D[1][3] = "Morgoth";
        quiz2D[1][4] = "Melkor";
        quiz2D[1][5] = "Super evil guy!";

        quiz2D[2][2] = "Radagast";
        quiz2D[2][3] = "Isildur son of Elendil";
        quiz2D[2][4] = "Adar";
        quiz2D[2][5] = "Tom Bombadil";

        quiz2D[3][3] = "1954";
        quiz2D[3][4] = "1917";
        quiz2D[3][5] = "1945";
        quiz2D[3][6] = "1943";

        //Question 1 input + output

        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(quiz2D[0][i]);
        }
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String a = sc.next(); //this will take the user's input
        if ((quiz2D[0][2].toLowerCase().equals(a.toLowerCase()))){
            System.out.println("You are correct! The answer is Maiar!");
        } 
        else {
            System.out.println("Nope, sorry.");
        }

        System.out.println(" "); // adds space before question


        //Question 2 input + output

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(quiz2D[1][i]);
        }
        Scanner sx = new Scanner(System.in);
        String ax = sx.next(); //this will take the user's input
        if ((quiz2D[1][4].toLowerCase().equals(ax.toLowerCase()))) {
            System.out.println("You are correct! The answer is Melkor!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Nope, sorry.");
        }


        System.out.println(" "); // adds space before question

        //Question 3 input + output

        System.out.println("Who is the character that lived in the woods not featured in the films?");
        for (int i = 2; i <= 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(quiz2D[2][i]);
        }
        Scanner scnq3 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String scannerQuestion3 = scnq3.next(); //this will take the user's input
        if ((quiz2D[2][5].toLowerCase().equals(scannerQuestion3.toLowerCase()))){
            System.out.println("You are correct!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Nope, sorry.");
        }

        System.out.println("When was the lord of the rings published?");
        for (int i = 3; i <= 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(quiz2D[3][i]);
        }
        Scanner scnq4 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String scannerQuestion4 = scnq3.next(); //this will take the user's input
        if ((quiz2D[3][3].toLowerCase().equals(scannerQuestion4.toLowerCase()))) {
            System.out.println("You are correct!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Nope, sorry.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your `for` loop doesn't go to that index.

```java
for (int i = 3; i <7; i++) {
        System.out.println(quiz2D[3][i]);
    }
```

[image: Outpu]

Is this your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with the question number 3 (so quiz2D[2][i], about "Who is the character that lived in the woods not featured in the films?") and it works. Here are the small changes :

```
quiz2D[2][0] = "Radagast";
quiz2D[2][1] = "Isildur son of Elendil";
quiz2D[2][2] = "Adar";
quiz2D[2][3] = "Tom Bombadil";
```

/****/

```
//Question 3 input + output

System.out.println("Who is the character that lived in the woods not featured in the films?");
for(int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
    System.out.println(quiz2D[2][i]);
}Scanner scnq3 = new Scanner(System.in);
String scannerQuestion3 = scnq3.next(); //this will take the user's input
if ((quiz2D[2][3].toLowerCase().equals(scannerQuestion3.toLowerCase()))){
    System.out.println("You are correct!");
}else{
    System.out.println("Nope, sorry.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you start your for loops at the question number, `i=2` for example. When you start your for loops on `i=0` the question wil be printed first and after that your answers.

The following example should work:

```java
for(int i = 0; i<=5; i++) {
    System.out.println(quiz2D[2][i]);
}

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String a = sc.next(); //this will take the user's input

if ((quiz2D[2][2].toLowerCase().equals(a.toLowerCase())))
{
    System.out.println("You are correct! The answer is Maiar!");
}
else{
    System.out.println("Nope, sorry.");
}
```

Hope this helps you!